# Flask PyCharm Syntax error

Tags: flask, pycharm

I've just started developing a new application using Flask and PyCharm as my IDE. 
I've encountered a problem which is driving me crazy.

Here is the code. I'll spare use all the import part and so on, I'll show only the routes that cause problems.

```
@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("home.html")

@app.route("/login/") 
def login():
    return "foo"
```

The first route works without a problem. However on the first line of the second route, PyCharm gives me an error message '"@" or "def" expected'. This breaks the autoindent and the auto completion features.

But the code runs without a problem.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Thank you

Comment: What version of PyCharm are you using?

Comment: It's PyCharm 4.5.2 I believe it's the most recent one.

Answer (score 1):

This is because PyCharm is not able to recognize the flask package or version.

Once you add new project to PyCharm -

1. Go to `File` menu item
2. Click on `Settings` option
3. This will open-up the pop-up window.
4. In the left-hand-side link list - click on the project name
5. Click on the `Project Interpreter` link
6. In the right-hand-side pane select `Flask` and `related packages` that your project needs and add/install the same.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately all the needed packages are already installed so this is not the solution. At the momemtn I'm just using the Flask package which is at version 0.10.1 and Flask-MySQL which is at version 1.3

Comment: well, it does remove the red error sign, but why?? code working with red error

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was (I was missing `pycharm's python environment` dependencies for python)

If you don't already have a requirements file for your project.
Navigate to your project & this on your command line (as I used a `venv` virtual environment):

(venv)$ `pip freeze > requirements.txt`

Then Open your pycharm and open the requirements file, wait a second or two and a pop up notification will show up at the top showing you are missing dependencies and will provide you a `click here` to install.

After that I had no issues.